# Download drawn shapefile from OSM

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap

What is the best way to download a drawn polygon from Open Street Maps such as https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/438407238#map=13/50.7733/6.1079 with the goal of obtaining a shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

[**QuickOSM**](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) (plugin) for QGIS will be the quick way.

settings in the query (zoom to your area of interest or you will get more boundaries)

**key=boundary
value=low_emission_zone**

you will get a temporary/scratch layer in QGIS when the query is successful

right click the temporary layer >save as shapefile.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising. Can you please tell me how to load the OSM layer into QGIS? I suppose this is what needs to be done first, correct?

Comment: As the answer says: use QuickOSM plugin with the query used - that's how you load the area there. To get an OSM basemap (not strictly necessary), go to XYZ tiles in the Browser panel and drag and drop OpenStreetMap to you Layers panel.